# createDataPartition function not working in Rstudio

Tags: r

code:

```
validation_index <- createDataPartition(dataset$Accepectance.Rate, p=0.80, list=FALSE)
```

> Error in createDataPartition(dataset$Accepectance.Rate, p = 0.8, list = FALSE) :
> could not find function "createDataPartition"

My dataset is of 400 observations and 8 variables.
Could anyone suggest what's wrong with this, although I have install the required packages

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `library` or `require` after installing if you want to use a function from the package `caret`. For example:

```
library(caret)
```

or

```
require(caret)
```

should be run before you use the function `createDataPartition()`

You can also use the function as `caret::createDataPartition()`.

Comment: @Purvi can you try using `caret::createDataPartition()` and let us know what happens? Btw, if you want your problem to be solved as quickly as possible, please share some reproducible data. It always works better that way :)

Comment: Thanks it worked, also I added " " for the dataset.                                   
validation_index <- caret::createDataPartition(dataset$"Accepectance.Rate", p=0.80, list=FALSE)